# Add Macros not stored in normal.dotm to a toolbar in Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I know I can customise a toolbar in Microsoft Word 2011 (there is a fairly comprehensive guide [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/1158396/wordtoolbars.html)).

My question is the following:

When I select "Macros" in the "Command" tab of the "Customize Toolbars and Menus" window, Word will only show me Macros contained in normal.dotm, not the ones in the current active document or the ones in the template this current document is based on, *even though* I can opt to save the customised toolbar in the document or the template, so it seems there is no logical reason to restrict the choice of macros that I can drag into the toolbar to only those macros in normal.dotm. So my question is:

Is there a way to place macros contained in the document template or the document, or more broadly, macros outside the normal.dotm, into a customised toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is an error in the dialog. But the precise sequence of steps needed to fix it is not clear.

What seems to work here is that when you go into "Customize Toolbars and Menus"

- Select the Toolbars and Menus tab
- Change the customization context from Normal.dotm to your .dotm
  and/or .docm (Sometimes I seem to have had to change it to normal.dotm, then back again)
- Click the Commands tab, then select the Macros category.
- You should then see the (Public) macros contained in your .dotm
- Selet the actual customization context that you want
- Select the macro and put it where you want in the menu structure.

Comment: Thanks. This is one silly bug. If I do the context switching after switching tabs, I can't see my macros, but following your sequence, I can. Cheers!